# Android: Opening a dialog actiivty without pausing current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that plays a video, and then on click of a button a new dialog activity opens while the video in that background pauses. Is there a way to start the dialog activity while keeping the previous activity running (as in not paused)? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

According to the link above, the current activity will be paused.

Just a suggestion, you can use fragment instead of a new dialog activity if you don't want onPause state. A custom alert dialog might be useful as well.

Comment: I cant use fragments due to the app supporting android 2.3. However, a custom dialog seems to work fine. Thank You.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity will be paused once you start the Dialog, but you don't necessarily have to pause the video on `onPause()` and the video will continue playing even though the Activity is paused as long it's visible.